# About the orthonormal decomposition of $L^2 (-\pi , \pi) $

Tags: fourier-analysis

For any $f \in L^2 (-\pi, \pi)$, prove that there exists unique orthonormal decomposition with even functions and odd functions : $$ L^2 ( -\pi , \pi) = L^2 _{odd} (-\pi , \pi ) \oplus L^2_{even} (-\pi , \pi).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also think this way. Suppose the $f = g + h$, $g$ is even and $h$ is odd. Then you have

$$f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$$

and

$$f(-x) = g(-x) + h(-x) = g(x) - h(x)),$$
since $g$ is even and $h$ is odd.  Add these two equations and you get
$$f(x) + f(-x) = 2g(x)$$
and 
$$ f(x) - f(-x) = 2h(x).$$
Hence you have
$$g(x) = {f(x) + f(-x)\over 2} $$
and
$$h(x) = {f(x) - f(-x)\over 2}.$$
It is easy to check that $g$ is in fact even and that $f$ is in fact odd.

We see that, algebraically, $L^2$ decomposes as a direct sum into even and odd parts.  Now if $g$ is any even function and $f$ is odd, $f\overline g$ is odd.  So
$$\langle f, g\rangle_{L^2} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x){\overline g}(x)\, dx = 0.$$

The decomposition is orthogonal.
This is where Norbert's answer comes from.

Comment: Thank you ncmathsadist, but how can I prove the uniqueness?

Comment: Notice that uniqueness is built into this argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a given $f\in L^2((-\pi,\pi))$ consider functions
$$
\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}
$$